Double meaning of “joined in marriage”
“I joined in marriage Ben and Nicole." When the officiant writes it in the marriage certificate can it have a double meaning?
The first meaning is- I united in marriage Ben and Nicole, meaning I married them.
The second meaning can be- I joined in the marriage of Ben and Nicole ( I participated in their marriage).
Can ”marriage Ben and Nicole” be a correct phrase? Is it correct to say “marriage Ben and Nicole” like it is a short way of saying “the marriage of Ben and Nicole”?
Thank you!!!

Cross-posting from ELU.

No, it can't. Join in marriage is a phrasal verb. 'Marriage Ben and Nicole' might be a note you would put in your diary, but it isn't a valid phrase in normal speech or writing.

If you want to say "I participated in their marriage", you need to say "I joined in the wedding of Ben and Nicole", although this is very clumsy ... "attended / went to" would be better. "Marriage" is used for the state or act of being married. "I participated in their marriage" would imply you were part of the relationship!

Simple part: In English, we do not say, "marriage Ben and Nicole". We say, "THE marriage OF Ben and Nicole". About the only way to shorten it would be to say "Ben and Nicole's marriage", or I suppose "their marriage" if we knew who you were talking about.
To "join in marriage" has a clearly understood meaning in English. It means the act of a priest or minister or whatever officiant in performing the ceremony that results in these two people being legally married, or married in the eyes of the church. We normally say, "He joined Ben and Nicole in marriage".
It would not be understood to mean he simply attended the wedding, or that he also got married. Such a usage might be part of a joke. Like, "I joined Ben and Nicole in marriage. They got married first and then later I got married, so I joined them in being married." Maybe you could work out some way to make that funny. But I say it would be a joke because you would be twisting the conventionally understood meaning of the word "join" in this context.
If you want to say that you attended their wedding, you would say, "I attended the wedding of Bob and Nicole" or "I went to the wedding of ..." or "I was a guest at the wedding of ..."
Note that this meaning is very different from how the word is used in other contexts. If you said, "I joined Bob and Nicole at the restaurant", we would understand you to mean that you met them there and probably the three (or more) of you had dinner together. I suppose there might be some ambiguity if a minister said, "I joined Bob and Nicole at a restaurant." Does he mean he performed a wedding there, or just that he went there with them? Again, the kind of ambiguity that might be used in a joke.

You are correct that both meanings which you've described are grammatically possible. But, in actual usage, the sentence

I joined in marriage Ben and Nicole.

would probably only be understood to mean #1: I united Ben and Nicole in marriage.
The second alternative is much less likely, especially since you give the context of an officiant writing on a marriage certificate. This makes it very clear that the first meaning is intended.

With regard to the syntax of the sentence as it relates to meaning #2: I joined in the marriage of Ben and Nicole, the words "the" and "of" are not required for the sentence to be grammatical. I wouldn't say that the grouping of words "marriage Ben and Nicole" constitutes a phrase, though.
Instead, when the second meaning is intended (which would require a very specific context to override the tendency to choose interpretation #1), the sentence can be parsed as follows:

[I subject] [joined main verb] [in marriage adverbial phrase, modifies "joined"] [Ben and Nicole compound direct object (of transitive verb "joined")].


So, what kind of context would make the second meaning a reasonable choice, and preclude the first?
This can be seen by way of analogy to a similar sentence that does not allow any ambiguity in interpretation. Consider the following scenario:
Alice and Bob are on vacation in Florida. They are joined by a friend Carol, who takes a later flight and so arrives after them. When Carol arrives, you can say:

She joined in Florida Alice and Bob, who had already been there 2 days.

Note, though, that although it is technically grammatically correct, the phrasing of this sentence is fairly awkward. You may come across a sentence like this in writing, where the unusual word order might be chosen for stylistic value. But, I very much doubt anyone would use that kind of syntax spontaneously, in a conversation! A much more natural word order would be "She joined Alice and Bob in Florida, after they had already been there 2 days."
To relate this back to the 'marriage' example, suppose you have two couples who are both getting married within a short timespan. When the second couple gets married, they could say that they are 'joining the first couple in marriage' -- as in, joining them in the state of being married (as opposed to single). The fact that it is a different couple, and not the celebrant, saying that sentence is how the listener would know to choose interpretation #2 instead of #1.

Also grammatically possible is the interpretation that I became a third member in their marriage, ie the marriage became a union of three instead of a union of two.both of them.

The triple would actually be my default interpretation of "I joined in the marriage of Alice and Bob" (I see the "in" as being optional, but the "of" is required).

@SoronelHaetir, Peter: Good catch, but I think this answer is already long enough as it is. Maybe you'd be interested in contributing your own answer?
